# dateFromString gives nil, swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception, nsdate

I am trying to create a NSDate object from a String. I have hardcoded my string for you to see. When i am calling dateFromString on my string, the result will be nil, and i am getting an exception because of unwrapping a nil. 
I have pasted my code below.

Any ideas how to do this the right way?

Thank you very much!

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"

    let timeToParse = "19/10/2016 16:10"

    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeToParse)
    //date = nil?

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mmZZZ"
    let dateWithUTC = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Comment: you specify dd/MM/yyyy as input, and provide 4 digits for the year

Comment: Yes i typed in the wrong string, but it still gives me nil when having 4 digits on the year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've supplied `hh` for hours, but this expects a format with 1-12 hours (with at least 2 digits). Since you're using 24 hours format (`16:..`), you need to use specifier `HH` instead, e.g.:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
```

Also:

- avoid using explicit unwrapping of optionals (`!`), use e.g. optional binding (`if let ...`) instead, and
- consider migrating to Swift 3: it's now official.

E.g. (Swift 3)

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

let timeToParse = "19/10/2016 16:10"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: timeToParse) {
    print(date) // 2016-10-19 16:10:00 +0000
}
```